# Error "all entries of 'x' must be nonnegative and finite"

Tags: r, chi-squared

I'd like to find out if there's a statistically significant difference in the conversion rate between two categories.

My data looks like this

```
    operating_system converted
1             Mac     FALSE
2             Mac     FALSE
3         Windows     FALSE
4         Windows      TRUE
5         Windows     FALSE
6             Mac      TRUE
7             Mac     FALSE
8         Windows     FALSE
9             Mac     FALSE
10            Mac     FALSE
```

I ran this code.

```
chisq.test(df)
```

And I received this error.

> Error in chisq.test(df) :    all entries of 'x' must be nonnegative
>   and finite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chisq.test` uses a contingency table :

```
df <- data.frame(operating_system = c("Mac", "Mac", "Windows", "Windows", "Windows", "Mac", "Mac", "Windows", "Mac", "Mac"),
             converted = c(F, F, F, T, F, T, F, F, F, F), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

chisq.test(table(df))
```